# navbar-toggler does not collpase when redirected to a new page

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

When I click on the toggler I see the menu expanded. While expanded, I click on a link on the page which takes me to another page. The toggler does not collpase/reset, it remains open. How do I ensure the toggler collapses when redirected to another page.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**CODE:**

```html
<div class="col-3">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-bg collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText"
                aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse m-nav" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-item-panel">
                <li class="nav-item-mn"><a id="homeLink" class="nav-text" routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item-mn"><a id="logoffLink" class="nav-text" routerLink="/" (click)="logout()">Logoff</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item-mn">
                    <a id="contactsLink" class="nav-text" href="https://studentaid.alberta.ca/contacts/" target="_blank"
                        title="Contacts">Contacts</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this method just as the new page loads to make sure your collapsible closes.

```
$('#navbarText').collapse('hide')
```

Or you can also target your collapse element and remove the`show` class if it exists

You can read more about it in the Bootstrap Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#methods

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the link to additional information. I appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I can help